# Can I calculate the distance between nodes that have longitude and latitude?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb, opencypher, memgraph

I will expand the dataset of capital cities that I have with longitude and latitude for each city. After that I would like to calculate the distance in kilometers between cities, or to calculate the total distance. Something similar that you can do in Via Michelin or Google Maps.

Do I need to add relations with distance between each city (like I found in https://playground.memgraph.com/sandbox/europe-roads) or can I use coordinates to calculate how far is one city from another?

I'm looking for equivalent of

```
MATCH p = (:City {name: "Zagreb"})
 -[:Road * wShortest (e, v | e.length) total_weight]->
 (:City {name: "Paris"})
RETURN nodes(p) AS cities, total_weight;
```

But when I don't have weights, but I have coordinates.

Comment: "_Can I calculate the distance between nodes that have longitude and latitude?_" Yes, you can. It's not Euclidean distance though, and there are existing libraries that can do this.

Comment: I guess that it is even better if it is not Euclidean distance . Eucledian distance is a straight line, and I think that if algorithm takes curvature into consideration it might be even better, more precise in terms of real travel distance. Or is my premise wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memgraph has a [distance_calculator](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/available-algorithms/distance_calculator) algorithm that calculates the "distance between two geographic locations". The algorithm has procedures for calculating either `single` or `multiple` distances.

However, Memgraph does not seem to provide a way to directly use that algorithm in a shortest path calculation.

But the workaround is to use the `distance_calculator` algorithm to calculate and store the geometric distance between the endpoints of every `Road` relationship (as a relationship property), and then use Memgraph's [weighted-shortest-path](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/built-in-graph-algorithms#weighted-shortest-path) algorithm to calculate the shortest path between any 2 cities.